# xAxis Categories Highcharts

Tags: mysql, yii, highcharts, yii2, query-builder

I want to choose 2011 up to 2015 from my table. Here is the table:

[image]

So, I made query like this

```
$tahunmasukpelamar = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(['TahunMasuk'])
        ->from('temp_jkpelamarmagister')
        ->Where(['between', 'TahunMasuk', 2007, 2011])
        ->column();

    $lakilakipelamar = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(['Lakilaki'])
        ->from('temp_jkpelamarmagister')
        ->column();

    $perempuanpelamar = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(['Perempuan'])
        ->from('temp_jkpelamarmagister')
        ->column();
    $lainlainpelamar = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(['Lainlain'])
        ->from('temp_jkpelamarmagister')
         ->column();

    $lakilakipelamar = array_map('floatval', $lakilakipelamar);
    $perempuanpelamar = array_map('floatval', $perempuanpelamar);
    $lainlainpelamar = array_map('floatval', $lainlainpelamar);

    $data['tahunmasukpelamar'] = json_encode($tahunmasukpelamar);
    $data['lakilakipelamar'] = json_encode($lakilakipelamar);
    $data['perempuanpelamar'] = json_encode($perempuanpelamar);
    $data['lainlainpelamar'] = json_encode($lainlainpelamar);
```

That is the **controller** too.

I have **View**:

```
$(function () {
    $('#my-chart').highcharts({
        chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Jumlah Pelamar Magister Berdasarkan Jenis Kelamin'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: $tahunmasukpelamar
    },
    yAxis: 
    {
        title: 
        {
           text: 'Jumlah'
        }
    },
    credits:
    {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
            name: 'Laki-Laki',
            data: $lakilakipelamar
        }, {
            name: 'Perempuan',
            data: $perempuanpelamar
        },
        {
            name: 'Lainnya',
            data: $lainlainpelamar
        }]
});
});
")?>
</div>
</div>
```

But, why my chart could appear like this:

[image]

What may I do to fix that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why `$tahunmasukpelamar`is between 2007 and 2011 and others are not. `$tahunmasukpelamar` is category form 2007 to 2011 and rest are 2004 to 2015. So have same range in all  database query.

Comment: maybe you should combine the query like this select tahun masuk, lakilaki, perempuan, lainnya from `your table` where tahunmasuk >= 2007 and tahunmasuk <= 2011.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned *I want to choose 2011 up to 2015 from my table*

Change query like this

```
$tahunmasukpelamar = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select(['TahunMasuk'])
    ->from('temp_jkpelamarmagister')
    ->Where(['between', 'TahunMasuk', 2011, 2015])
    ->column();

$lakilakipelamar = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select(['Lakilaki'])
    ->from('temp_jkpelamarmagister')
    ->Where(['between', 'TahunMasuk', 2011, 2015])
    ->column();

$perempuanpelamar = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select(['Perempuan'])
    ->from('temp_jkpelamarmagister')
    ->Where(['between', 'TahunMasuk', 2011, 2015])
    ->column();
$lainlainpelamar = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select(['Lainlain'])
    ->from('temp_jkpelamarmagister')
    ->Where(['between', 'TahunMasuk', 2011, 2015])
    ->column();
```

All others code are same